# Block requests to "Visual Search" in Edge and "Search images with Google" in Chrome for internal web application

Tags: firewall, web-applications, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

We have a web application that is used internally that displays highly confidential images.

Microsoft Edge has started displaying a button on the images that launches Visual Search, and Chrome has a context menu function that launches a Google Lens image search.

Presumably, both these involve sending the image to Microsoft/Google, and the ease of access of these functions makes it tempting for users to do this. In particular, because Edge actually displays a button on top of the image, it looks like it is an authorized feature of our website.

Is there a way to block this? I can think of three approaches:

a) add some tags or styling to the web page to tell the browser not to do this

b) add some group policies that turn off these features in the browsers

c) block the requests at a firewall level

Has anyone been able to do this?